# On finding jobs as a student in Germany: Documents required

Tags: germany, job-hunting

In my visa, it's written, I can work in student job during my studies in Germany. I would like to ask in regards to this,

1. Where can I find job listings specifically for students in Germany?
2. What are the required documents for being able to apply to a student job?

Answer (score 0):

> […] Where can I find job listings specifically for students in Germany? […]

- My alma mater in Germany had a job board for students.
  It is internal and requires login with your student ID.
  Maybe your college has such a job board, too?
- Hamburg University Marketing sells a brand *Stellenwerk* (“vacancies
  plant/factory”).
  Multiple location‑specific job boards *predominately* listing vacancies for university students are marketed under the brand *Stellenwerk* and maybe so at your location.
- Today, lots of jobs, especially those targeting young populations (i. e. most college students), aren’t advertised in such a formal manner as it used to be.
  If you use so‑called “social media” you may find appropriate “groups” for your location.
  It’s worth a shot.
- Otherwise you *can* use search engines, right?
  You can enter the keyword *studentisch* in the search form of the [“Job Exchange” of the Federal Employment Agency](https://Jobboerse.Arbeitsagentur.de) combined with your location.

  There are no legal limitations on hiring students for “non‑student” positions.
  It’s just a statement that employers accommodate for student needs (e. g. less work during the finals).

> […] What are the required documents for being able to apply to a student job?

To *apply* for a job you don’t need no specific documents.
To be *hired* you’ll need to prove your work permit.
For foreigners this is usually the card‑sized *elektronischer Aufenthaltstitel*.